# Kotlin: Implement generic Interface multiple times with different Subclasses (Base Class is Constraint)

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, constraints

Error Msg: Type parameter E of 'SchedulableInserter' has inconsistent values: Incident, Assignment

So basically I have an abstract class Schedulable.
Also I have two classes Incident (Single occuring event, like a timestamp)
and a class Assignment(Basically an Incident but with a duration too)
I have a MainActivity, where I want to insert Instances into a SQLiteDB.
I want to have a different insert-method for every subclass of Schedulable
to easily handle the differences between them.

//SchedulableInserter.kt

```
interface SchedulableInserter<E> where E : Schedulable{
        fun onInsertSchedulable(item:E)
}
```

//MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(),
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
    SchedulableInserter<Incident>, SchedulableInserter<Assignment> {
 /* ^                                ^
    |                                |
   Sadly Kotlin says:
   Type parameter E of 'SchedulableInserter' has inconsistent values: 
   Incident, Assignment
   A Supertype apperars twice
*/
}
```

I mean I could differentiate within the method if i bind SchedulerInserter to Schedulable, but I would appreciate not having to do that.

Comment: Looks like a problem of generics and type erasure. You can't have two different `SchedulableInserter<>` supertypes because they conflict with each other, even though one is `<Incident>` and the other is `<Assignment>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I'd suggest is having the inserters as properties in the activity instead of implemented interfaces:

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(),
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    val incidentInserter = SchedulableInserter<Incident> { ... }
    val assignmentInserter = SchedulableInserter<Assignment> { ... }
}
```

To make [that syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) available you [currently](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770) need to define `SchedulableInserter` in Java instead of Kotlin; otherwise you have to write

```
    val incidentInserter = object : SchedulableInserter<Incident> { 
        override fun ...
    }
```

Comment: How do we then use these objects??

Comment: Can you give more context? Without it, I can just answer "the same way you use any object, there's nothing special about them".

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Ben P.

Solution:

> I mean I could differentiate within the method if i bind
>   SchedulerInserter to Schedulable, but I would appreciate not having to
>   do that.